# ¿Como eliminar un nodo por posición (indice) de una lista simple?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito ayuda para eliminar un nodo por posición, el ejercicio dice que borre los nodos que están en posición par si la cantidad de nodos es par.

Eso lo hago con el metodo `getTamanio()` que me dice el tamaño de la lista.

Tengo el código para borrar un nodo en especifico pero este lo elimina al comparar el dato que ingreso con el que esta guardado.

Deberia borrar los nodos donde estan guardado el 3,5,7 ya que son posiciones pares si empezamos desde 0.

```
ListaSimple l= new ListaSimple();


        l.agregarAlFinal(1);
        l.agregarAlFinal(2);
        l.agregarAlFinal(3);
        l.agregarAlFinal(4);
        l.agregarAlFinal(5);
        l.agregarAlFinal(6);
        l.agregarAlFinal(7);
        l.agregarAlFinal(8);

        for (int j=0;j<8;j++){

            if (l.getTamanio()%2==0){


                //System.out.println("Es par");
                l.eliminarElemento("Aqui no se que pasarle, es el problema");


            }
```

Metodo eliminarElemento();

```
public void eliminarElemento(A valor) {
        if (!esVacia()) {
            if (inicio == fin && valor == inicio.getValor()) {
                inicio = fin = null;
            } else if (valor == inicio.getValor()) {
                inicio = inicio.getSiguiente();
            } else {
                Nodo anterior, temporal;
                anterior = inicio;
                temporal = inicio.getSiguiente();
                while (temporal != null && temporal.getValor() != valor) {
                    anterior = anterior.getSiguiente();
                    temporal = temporal.getSiguiente();

                }
                if (temporal != null) {
                    anterior.setSiguiente(temporal.getSiguiente());
                    if (temporal == fin) {
                        fin = anterior;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: El método eliminar elemento es el de siempre en todas las listas, no sé si tenga que usar ese o otro método.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene el método `eliminarElemento`?

Comment: @smt hola, acabo de añadir el metodo, recibe un valor sea el tipo de dato que sea y lo compara con los que estan guardados en el nodo, si coincide borrar el nodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí un ejemplo de como eliminar las posiciones pares:

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        lista.add(1);
        lista.add(2);
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(4);
        lista.add(5);
        lista.add(6);
        lista.add(7);
        lista.add(8);

        //MUESTRA TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA LISTA
        for (Integer numero : lista) {
            System.out.print(numero + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();

        //SE CREA UNA LISTA CON LOS ELEMENTOS ELIMINADOS 3,5,7
        List<Integer> listaEliminada = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int j = 0; j < lista.size(); j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0 && j != 0) {
                listaEliminada.add(lista.get(j));
            }
        }

        //ELIMINA LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA LISTA
        for (Integer numero : listaEliminada) {
            lista.remove(numero);
        }

        //MUESTRA LA LISTA CON LOS ELEMENTOS ELIMINADOS
        for (Integer numero : lista) {
            System.out.print(numero + ",");
        }
```

A continuación el resultado con los elementos eliminados:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
>
> 1,2,4,6,8,

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro que debes pasar a eliminarElemento() es **j**.
Cuando estás recorriendo tu lista, **j** es la posición del elemento que contiene la lista;
por lo que si la pasas por parámetros, estás pasando la posición del elemento que quieres eliminar.

```
ListaSimple l= new ListaSimple();


    l.agregarAlFinal(1);
    l.agregarAlFinal(2);
    l.agregarAlFinal(3);
    l.agregarAlFinal(4);
    l.agregarAlFinal(5);
    l.agregarAlFinal(6);
    l.agregarAlFinal(7);
    l.agregarAlFinal(8);

    for (int j=0;j<9;j++){

        if (l.getTamanio()%2==0){

            //System.out.println("Es par");
            l.eliminarElemento(j);

        }
```

Comment: No funciona ya que eliminarElemento() recibe un parametro y compara ese parametro con los valores que esten guardados en el nodo, eso quiere decir que ahi va a recibir int del 0 al 8 no mas.

Answer (score 0):

La función de este método es la siguiente, Si la cantidad de elementos es par, solo deja los elementos que están en índices pares, Si la cantidad es impar entonces solo deja los elementos que están en índices impares.

```
public void eliminarIndices() {
    Nodo aux = inicio;
    if (this.cantidadElementos % 2 == 0) {
        //si es par la cantidad de elementos solo deja indices pares
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadElementos; i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                eliminar(aux.getDato());
            }
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }

    } else {
        //si es impar la cantidad de elementos solo deja indices impares
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadElementos; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                eliminar(aux.getDato());
            }
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }
    }
}
```

Método eliminar()

```
public void eliminar(int elemento) {
    if (!vacia()) {
        if (inicio == fin && elemento == inicio.getDato()) {
            inicio = fin = null;
        } else if (elemento == inicio.getDato()) {
            inicio = inicio.getSiguiente();
        } else {
            Nodo anterior = inicio;
            Nodo temporal = inicio.getSiguiente();
            while (temporal != null && temporal.getDato() != elemento) {
                anterior = anterior.getSiguiente();
                temporal = temporal.getSiguiente();
            }
            if (temporal != null) {

                anterior.setSiguiente(temporal.getSiguiente());
                if (temporal == fin) {
                    fin = anterior;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```